# How to convert an Rspec test with stubs to Minitest

Tags: ruby, rspec, minitest, stub

I'm trying to convert a test file from Rspec to Minitest, which up to this point has been going well (very simple tests thus far). But I've come across some **stubs** and I can't get them to function correctly.

Here is the original Rspec test:

```
it "takes exactly 1 second to run a block that sleeps for 1 second (with stubs)" do
    fake_time = @eleven_am
    Time.stub(:now) { fake_time }
    elapsed_time = measure do
        fake_time += 60  # adds one minute to fake_time
    end
    elapsed_time.should == 60
end
```

My attempt to convert that to Minitest:

```
it "takes exactly 1 second to run a block that sleeps for 1 second (with stubs)" do
    fake_time = @eleven_am
    Time.stub(:now, fake_time) do
        elapsed_time = measure { fake_time += 60 }
        elapsed_time.must_equal 60
    end
end
```

And the method these are testing:

```
def measure(rep=1, &block)
    start_time = Time.now
    rep.times { block.call }
    Time.now - start_time
end
```

The problem I'm having is that with Rspec, the stubs update dynamically with the method execution. When `fake_time` gets changed in the block, `Time.now` is immediately updated to correspond with that, meaning the final `Time.now` call is updated in my method, and it returns the appropriate difference (60).

With Minitest, I seem to override the `Time.now` response successfully, but it doesn't update with execution, so when `fake_time` gets adjusted, `Time.now` does not. This causes it to always return 0, as `start_time` and `Time.now` remain identical.

This is probably correct behavior for what it is, I'm just not sure how to get what I want out of it.

How do I make the Minitest stub act like the Rspec stub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received an answer from Chris Kottom on Reddit that I will share here.

The solution is to use a lambda:

```
Time.stub(:now, -> { fake_time }) do
    ...
end
```

This creates a dynamic stub that updates with your code execution.

If `fake_time` is a variable instead of a method (e.g. static vs. dynamic), you can represent this via:

```
Time.stub(:now, fake_time) do
    ...
end
```